# Logic for adding \ before every character in ADF parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement in ADF wherein i have a parameter which can contain following values AB or A or B
I want to update these values by appending \ in front of each character.
So the output should be as follows:

- For AB - \A\B
- For A - \A

How to append \ in front of every character irrespective of number of characters in a parameter?

Please note that we don't want to use DataFlow for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the native expressions in ADF. Either call an Azure function to perform the work, or use SQL and a Lookup Activity to perform the task. You can put the following into a dynamic expression referencing the following as an example;

```
declare @@str nvarchar(max) = 'helloworld'; /* get value in dynamic expression '@{@pipeline().parameters.PARAMETER_NAME}'*/
declare @@strOut nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @@strlen int = len(@@str);
declare @@i int = 1;

while @@i <= @@strlen
begin
 set @@strOut += concat('\',SUBSTRING(@@str,@@i,1));
 set @@i +=1;
end

select @@strOut [result];
```

Then fetch the result from the activity. e.g. `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.result`

*As seen below, note the UI is just adding the extra \ in the preview, (ADF rendering bug)*

[image]

The dynamic expression in the Lookup **Query** parameter :
[image]